# Doesnt JAVA EE SDK include the APIs in JAVA EE DOC?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, installation

I installed JAVA SE JDK and then installed JAVA EE SDK java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-windows-x64.exe
because the latter one requires a jre. But then I found that the java ee sdk is merely nothing new than java se but a combination of java se jdk+ glassfish platform. I do not know if I am right because I cannot find those "java ee" classes in it. (And the .jar files in jre/lib are the same) It is strange. Lets say JavaMail package, I cannot find it in my java ee jre but it is said this package is included in Java ee platform.

What I expected is the new apis and "java ee" source code which I could not find either. I really would like to know how to get a jdk which includes all the apis descripted at
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/

Can some one tell me if I am right about this issue (JAVA EE SDK does not contain JAVA EE API)? If I am right, do I need to get each jar lib from the internet when I use it? Then what is the different between java se + external lib and java ee? Or Did I make any mistake when I installed?

Thank you guys!

Comment: *I found that the java ee sdk is merely nothing new than java se but a combination of java se jdk+ glassfish platform.* That's normal because Java SE and Java EE are specifications implemented by various vendors. Java SE has many tastes: HotSpot (Oracle JDK), JRockit, OpenJDK... Java EE too: GlassFish 3.x, JBoss 6/7. Note: Tomcat is not a Java EE implementation, just a Servlet container.

Comment: Hi Thanks. But should JAVA EE have jar files like servlet-api.jar javamail.jar in it? Why I cannot see them in jre/lib?

Comment: Yes, a decent Java EE implementation will have those jars, but maybe they won't have the code you expect. Also, when you download the SDK, it just downloads the jars with .class files. Maybe you're using NetBeans which already has the default Oracle Java SE source and displays it to you. You shouldn't focus on the source. If you want to know info about the classes, read the [Java EE classes Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/)(check the API documentation link).

Comment: Sorry I did not make me clear enough. I do hope to get source code but for now I even could not find .class file. The JAVA EE installer from oracle.com only give java se jdk and glassfish, nothing else. There are a lot apis in java ee doc which are not in java se jdk, I wonder where I can get them.

Comment: It looks like you haven't installed well the Java EE SDK. Are you sure you're looking the jars inside the installed GlassFish (yes, this is the Java EE SDK)?